# Define diffent Foreground-Color in DataTemplate and Style

Tags: c#, wpf

for a TreeViewItem i use a DataTemplate. In this Template i define the Foreground-Color as blue. When i selected a TreeviewItem i would like have the Foreground-Color in white. My first thought was to create a Style, but the style doesn`t work. Obviously i make some wrong. Any idea?

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="styDriveTreeNode" DataType="{x:Type local:NodeDrive }">
        <Grid  Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="picDrv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="16" Width="16"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblDrvName" Content="{Binding HeaderLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  FontSize="12" Padding="0" Margin="2"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblDrvDetails" Content="{Binding HeaderDetails}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10" Padding="0" Margin="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemPartition}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="picDrv" Property="Source" Value="/Images/DriveWin16.png"/>
                <Setter TargetName="lblDrvName" Property="Foreground"  Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter TargetName="lblDrvDetails" Property="Foreground"  Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDrive}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="picDrv" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=imgDrv}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>

    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `Foreground` property to specific target name, therefore, you have to change the foreground of that specific `TargetName` as well. And you can achieve that within `Datatemplate.Triggers` as mentioned below.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="styDriveTreeNode" DataType="{x:Type local:NodeDrive }">
        <Grid  Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="picDrv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="16" Width="16"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblDrvName" Content="{Binding HeaderLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  FontSize="12" Padding="0" Margin="2"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblDrvDetails" Content="{Binding HeaderDetails}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10" Padding="0" Margin="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemPartition}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="picDrv" Property="Source" Value="/Images/DriveWin16.png"/>
                <Setter TargetName="lblDrvName" Property="Foreground"  Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter TargetName="lblDrvDetails" Property="Foreground"  Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDrive}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="picDrv" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=imgDrv}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="lblDrvName" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="lblDrvDetails" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Good morning. It works fine :-) I switch step by step from winforms to wpf. Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" is new from me. Thx for help! Btw: It is possible, to mark this thread as solved?